# Memory use keep increasing in for loop while using dynamic array.(C++)

Tags: c++, arrays

The following is my C++ code.

I found the memory use will keep increasing if I try to use test1 array to calculate anything.

```
double **test1;
test1=new double *[1000];

for(int i=0;i<1000;i++){
    test1[i]=new double [100000000];
    test1[i][0]=rand() / (double)RAND_MAX*100;
}

for(int j=1;j<100000000;j++){
    for(int i=0;i<1000;i++){
        test1[i][j]=test1[i][j-1];  //this cause memory use increase.
    }
}
```

If I delete the line.

```
test1[i][j]=test1[i][j-1];
```

The memory use will become a small constant value.

I thought I have already declare the dynamic array at the first part, the memory use should be a constant if I didn't new any array.

What cause the memory use increasing? And how do I avoid it?

(I use linux command "top" to monitor the memory use.)

Comment: not sure that it is that specific line that cause the memory increase but in general you just allocated 8 x 1,000 x 100,000,000 bytes of memory which is around 750GB. thanks @WhozCraig for the correction

Comment: I think this can be caused by a memory paging - the virtual memory might be allocated but until you access it it is not guaranteed it has assigned a physical memory. BTW don't use the `new`.

Comment: so... which means the computer will not assign the memory to the dynamic array until I use it to do something?

Comment: (8*1000*100000000) = 800000000000 bytes, 781250000 kB, 762939.45 mB, or 745.06 gB. hope you brought some disk space or that swap image.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the first loop you create 100,000,000 doubles, which is 800 MB of allocation.  You write to the first one only.

Later you write to the rest.  When you do this, the operating system needs to actually give you the memory to write into, whereas initially it just gave you a mapping which would page fault later (when you write to it).

So basically, since each allocation is so large, the memory required to back it is not physically allocated until it is used.

The code is nonsensical, because eventually you try to write to 800 GB of memory.  I doubt that will ever complete on a typical computer.

Comment: Thank you so much. I know the code is quite ridiculous, because I was trying to use an extreme condition to see what will happen in these cases. Thank you for your explanation. It helps a lot.

Answer (score 2):

On a virtual memory system, the Linux kernel will (by default) not actually allocate any physical memory when your program does an allocation. Instead it will just adjust your virtual address space size.
Think of it like the kernel going "hmm, yeah, you say you want this much memory. I'll remember I promised you that, but let's see if you are really going to use it before I go fetch it for you".
If you then actually go and write to the memory, the kernel will get a page fault for the virtual address that that is not actually backed by real memory and at that point it will go and allocate some real memory to back the page you wrote to.

Many programs never write to all the memory they allocate, so by only fulfilling the promise when it really has to, the kernel saves huge amounts of memory.

You can see the difference between the amount you have allocated and the amount that is actually occupying real memory bu looking at the VSS (Virtual Set Size) and RSS (Resident Set Size) columns in the output of `ps aux`.

If you want all allocations to be backed by physical memory all the time (you probably do not), then you can change the kernels overcommit policy via the `vm.overcommit_memory` `sysctl` switch.